# How to use Java to read/write data to/from the header pins?

Tags: gpio, linux, java, c

I just got Java running on my Raspberry Pi which took a lot more screwing around than i had hoped. I want to be able to read/write data to/from the header pins from Java. How can I do this? Do I need to write a driver or some sort with C first in order to get the data from the header pins? I am running an instance of Soft-float Debian “wheezy." Is this even possible to do in Java? Are there any workarounds that I should know about? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should be possible in Java, as referenced [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#GPIO_Driving_Example_.28Java.29). The library which is used is called rpi-gpio-java and is available at [this URL](http://code.google.com/p/rpi-gpio-java/). As stated in the notes, to make it work, please make sure your application is run as root.

Note: Above project rpi-gpio-java is no longer available on google code. Alternate option is [PI4J](http://pi4j.com/example/control.html)

Comment: This is interesting. Nice find Dexter.

Answer (score 3):

If you did not already foud your solution, [the Pi4J Library](http://pi4j.com), based on Wiring for the Raspberry Pi, offers - also on an early development stage - acces to GPIO, I2C and SPI. And Rs232, not to forget!

Serviceprovider for several IO-boards (Olimex etc.) are included.

Most interesting: Event driven processing (GPIO-Interrupts).

see: [here](http://pi4j.com)